# How Do You Get an Empty Response Body Using Declarative External Services

Tags: visual-workflow, external-services

*Note: This is for declarative External Services. We are not writing Apex but using the UI and Salesforce generates the Apex classes. I need to include this until the name of this is changed by SFDC*

The OpenAPI 2.0 schema says,

> Some responses, such as 204 No Content, have no body. To indicate the
> response body is empty, do not specify a schema for the response.
> Swagger treats no schema as a response without a body.

Doing the above does not generate an Apex Class for the 200 response though which appears to cause an error as Salesforce needs to put the `{}` somewhere. How do we write the schema to support this empty response?

> Using a variable name of "" does not seem to work either and not
> recognized by Salesforce

This is what the OpenApi 2.0 suggests but does not work in Salesforce.

```
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "success"
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggested way is working. It looks like problem was fixed if using API 51.0 for Flow. When I changed flow to that, which was being overwritten when I deployed flow using DX CLI, then the problem went away.